# How to import nested component's dependencies angular 6

Tags: angular, module, components

I'm trying to create two components: 
Configuracion and Equipo
**configuracion.component.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
    import { ConfiguracionComponent }   from './configuracion.component';
    import { routing } from './configuracion.routing';  
    import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
    import { ProgressHttpModule } from "angular-progress-http";  
    import { EquipoComponent } from './equipo/equipo.component';
    import { EquipoModule } from './equipo/equipo.module';
    //import { SortablejsModule } from 'angular-sortablejs';
    // import { ImageCropperModule } from '../image-cropper/image-cropper.module';
        @NgModule({
    imports: [routing,CommonModule,EquipoModule,  FormsModule
      ],
    declarations: [ConfiguracionComponent, EquipoComponent]
    })
    export class ConfiguracionModule {}
```

**equipo.component.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { EquipoComponent } from './equipo.component';


import { SortablejsModule } from 'angular-sortablejs';
import { ImageCropperModule } from '../../image-cropper/image-cropper.module';

import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { ProgressHttpModule } from "angular-progress-http";

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule ,HttpModule,ProgressHttpModule
],
declarations: [

],
exports: [
    SortablejsModule,ImageCropperModule
]
})
export class EquipoModule {}
```

This code works but...
Why I had to **export** the dependencies of equipo (SortablejsModule,ImageCropperModule) and **import** in configuracion.module?

Can you provide me a good tutorial for this angular topic?

Thanks for reading :D

Comment: You are showing `module` files code in the name of `component` files. Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:
[Understanding Angular modules (NgModule) and their scopes](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407)